# MoveableJS: Ignore user input but still allow programmatic move/resize/rotate

Tags: javascript, moveable

I can't seem to find any simple way to do this, so any pointers would be helpful.

I want to be able to toggle draggable/resizable/etc., preferably when the element is clicked, to ignore human input, but still allow programmatic movement calling moveable.request().

Disabling .draggable prevents user dragging, but it also shuts off click events and the necessary drag events for repositioning are never fired when calling moveable.request().

However, I've been able to effectively toggle all other -ables by setting the moveable.className which either shows or hides the moveable-control-box, but the element still remains draggable, which is not desired.

In short - I want all -ables to be active, but ignore human input (except click) with the element is marked "inactive".